# os.path.exists gives different results on the same file

Tags: python, file, os.path

Here's the code for the reference:

```py
    import shutil
    import datetime
    import os.path
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


    if not os.path.exists('copy_path.txt'):
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()

        file_to_backup = askopenfilename(title=' ')
        backup_directory = askdirectory(title=' ')
        print(file_to_backup)
        print(os.path.exists(file_to_backup))

    if os.path.exists(file_to_backup):
        if os.path.exists(backup_directory):
            copy_path_file = open('copy_path.txt', 'w+')
            copy_path_file.write(file_to_backup + '\n' + backup_directory)
            copy_path_file.close()

    if os.path.exists('copy_path.txt'): 
        copy_path_file = open('copy_path.txt', 'r')
        paths = copy_path_file.readlines()
        #paths[0] = paths[0].replace('/','\\')
        print(paths[0])
        print(os.path.exists(paths[0]))
        print(os.path.isfile(paths[0]))
        print('----------------------')
        print(paths[1])
        print(os.path.exists(paths[1]))
        print(os.path.isdir(paths[1]))
        #copy_path_file.close()
        if os.path.exists(paths[0]):
            if os.path.exists(paths[1]):
                today = datetime.datetime.today()
                date = str(today.year) + "." + str(today.month) + "." + str(today.day) + "-" + str(today.hour) + "." + str(today.minute)
            index = paths[0].rfind('.')
            #new_path = paths[0][0:index-1] + date + paths[0][index:paths[0].len]
            #print(new_path)
            print(paths[0])

            #newPath = shutil.copy(paths[0], new_path)
```

My question is why does

**print(os.path.exists(file_to_backup))**

gives me **true** but

**print(os.path.exists(paths[0]))**

returns **false** when it's called on the same path?

---

Since my question wasn't asked with code made as minimal reproducible example, here's a shorter version:

```
import os.path
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

file_to_backup = askopenfilename(title=' ')
print(os.path.exists(file_to_backup))
copy_path_file = open('copy_path.txt', 'w+')
copy_path_file.write(file_to_backup + '\n' + 'backup_directory')
copy_path_file.close()

copy_path_file = open('copy_path.txt', 'r')
paths = copy_path_file.readlines()
print(os.path.exists(paths[0]))
```

This print returns true

But this returns false, the file_to_backup path was written to file and here after it has been read from the file, it returns false.

The answear provided by user jasonharper is the correct one, I had to delete the new line symbol after reading the path from file.

Comment: You need to make a [mre]

Comment: `paths` came from a call to `.readlines()`, which *preserves line endings* - `paths[0]` is going to have a newline at the end, which makes it an extremely unlikely name for an actual file.

Comment: Probably because `paths[0] != file_to_backup`

Comment: 1) It’s good cross-platform policy to open the files in `rt` or `wt` as you are reading/writing text. 2) you are opening `copy_file_path.txt` in `w+` so what you write will be appended, i.e. if there are already two lines in the file they won’t change. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Your latest edit still does not show a minimal reproducible example. Without knowing more about the context (contents of `copy_path.txt`) it is impossible to give a fully informed answer. Although, most likely the comment of @jasonharper is correct and should be formulated as an answer.